# How to reload page in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I would like to reload the page whenever the page doesn't load properly or encounters a problem. I tried `page.reload()` but it doesn't work.

```
for(const sect of sections ){

            // Now collect all the URLs
            const appUrls = await page.$$eval('div.main > ul.app-list > li > div.app-info a.app-info-icon', links => links.map(link => link.href));

            // Visit each URL one by one and collect the data
            for (let appUrl of appUrls) {
                var count = i++;
                try{
                    await page.goto(appUrl);
                    const appName = await page.$eval('div.det-name-int', div => div.innerText.trim());
                    console.log('\n' + count);
                    console.log(appName);
                } catch(e){
                    console.log('\n' + count);
                    console.log('ERROR', e);
                    await page.reload();
                }

            }

        }
```

It gives me this error:

```
    ERROR Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector "div.det-name-int"
    at ElementHandle.$eval (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\JS
Handle.js:418:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at ElementHandle.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\puppeteer\
lib\helper.js:108:27)
    at DOMWorld.$eval (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\DOMWorl
d.js:149:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\help
er.js:108:27)
    at Page.$eval (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:329
:29)
    at Page.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helpe
r.js:109:23)
    at main (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\webscrape\text.js:35:43)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Some links are unable to load successfully. When I refresh those pages manually, it works. So I hope there is a function or a method that can help me reload my page automatically when there is an error.

Comment: Is it throwing any errors? If so what is it? page.reload is a promise and you are not handling it. Try using it and see if it is getting executed or not

Comment: It doesn't seem to work?? What it means exactly ?

Comment: @Sammy  the page has a loading error

Comment: Could you perhaps attach a screenshot? There are many types of loading error. What is the HTTP status code? Maybe you're trying something illegal as termed by the site which is getting blocked or the remote server is down. We need more information about the error

Comment: @Sammy I included the error in the question.

Comment: Can you change **page.reload()** to **page.reload(response => console.log(response))** and add your output.

Comment: @Sammy it does not show anything in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to solve it using a while loop.

```
for (let appUrl of appUrls) {
    var count = i++;

    while(true){
        try{

            await page.goto(appUrl);

            const appName = await page.$eval('div.det-name-int', div => div.innerText.trim());

            console.log('\n' + count);
            console.log('Name: ' , appName);

            break;

            } catch(e){
              console.log('\n' + count);
              console.log('ERROR');
              await page.reload(appUrl);

              continue;
            }

}
```

Comment: Try to avoid while(true) statements, because if you encounter a page which doesn't have the links at all, then you will lock the main thread in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 62):

This works for me:

```
await page.reload({ waitUntil: ["networkidle0", "domcontentloaded"] });
```

See Puppeteer docs for details: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagereloadoptions

Comment: Here's an updated url for the docs: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.reload

Answer (score 11):

You always can reload page via DOM, like this:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
   location.reload(true)
})
```

or here is a [lot of ways](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html) how you can reload page with browser JS via DOM

Also, you can navigate your puppeteer [back and forward](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html). Like this:

```
await page.goBack();
await page.goForward();
```

Comment: Sometimes the first approach cause 'crashing' in puppeteer, I really recommend the second alternative.]

Answer (score 0):

So after the comments, the following line makes the error.

```
ERROR Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector "div.det-name-int"
```

bacause Puppetteer has a browser callback. When it finds the element and calls the callback, and if the element doesn't exist it throws an error.

Also, the page is reloaded. You're not doing anything after that. If you want to fetch the image after that. Use

```
await page.$eval('div.det-name-int', div => div.innerText.trim());
```

after the reload. Or you can have a while loop to continuously check whether the element exists. If it doesn't then refresh page and check again. This ensures you will always have content.

But if your content is dynamically generated and not part of the DOM at the moment you read the page, then your code becomes useless. You might need to add a timeout then search the dom for the element.